# Pyomo error about evaluating value of 'ScalarParam' parameter

Tags: optimization, python, pyomo

I'm trying to optimize a huge model, but here is a part of it capable of creating an understanding of my question:

```
model = ConcreteModel()


model.days = Set(initialize=RangeSet(31))

T = model.days

model.Y = Param(initialize=1) 

model.L= Param(initialize=330)  

model.LL= Param(initialize=3300) 

model.LU= Param(initialize=3300) 

model.U=  Param(initialize=250) 

model.X0=  Param(initialize=0) 

model.M= Var(T,bounds=(0, None), initialize = 10) 

model.X= Var(T,bounds=(0, None), initialize = 10) 

def obj_rule(model):
  return sum( model.X[i] for i in model.days )


model.funcobj = Objective( rule =obj_rule , sense=maximize)

def C1A_rule(model,t):
  return model.Y*model.L<= model.M[t]

def C1B_rule(model,t):
  return model.M[t] <= model.Y*model.U

model.C1A = Constraint(model.days, rule= C1A_rule)
model.C1B = Constraint(model.days, rule= C1B_rule)


def C14_rule(model,i): # constraints do balanço de massa para o setor b1
  if i == T[1]:  #Pyomo Sets are 1-indexed
    return (model.X[i] == model.M[i] + model.X0)
  if i != T[1]:   
    return (model.X[i] == model.M[i] + model.X[i-1]  )

model.C14 = Constraint( model.days, rule = C14_rule)


def C15A_rule(model,t):
  return model.LL<=   model.M[t] / 1.15741e-5
def C15B_rule(model,t):
  return  model.M[t] / 1.15741e-5   <=  model.LU


model.C15A = Constraint( model.days, rule= C15A_rule)
model.C15B = Constraint( model.days, rule= C15B_rule)




SolverFactory('glpk', executable='/usr/bin/glpsol').solve(model).write()
```

When the code is executed, the following error appears:

`ValueError: Evaluating the numeric value of parameter 'ScalarParam' before the Param has been constructed (there is currently no value to return).`

In this case, what should I do to avoid this error and get a normal completion status?

Comment: I run the code, there is no error and "Process finished with exit code 0" and "Termination condition: infeasible". I just remove the " executable='/usr/bin/glpsol" part from solverfactory definition.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I found the error, I just forgot to add a parameter to the model through model.parameter, thanks for all your good will!